# Run Java Bean without open browser

Tags: java, web-applications, glassfish, ejb, javabeans

I would like to run a web application and keep running a Class which inserts Data in a Database 24/7 without having a browser open.

If I open a browser I would just like to see which data is beeing inserted right now.

How would I keep this process running in a web application on a Glassfish server without having a website open?

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Do you want to controll the insertion of the data from the web as well or would it be ok to start a seperate batch application on the server for it?

Comment: No, I do not need to controll the insertion of the data via. The class which inserts into the database runs independentley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the data insertion into a plain old java application and start it via the main method.

With your web application show the current state of the data base. Add timestamps to your DB records. This allows to query for new records.